# Small c programming help needed

Tags: c

I have this problem I've been trying to get this done for last 7 hours, but I'm not getting anywhere. I have tried many options but I seem to fail all time. I'd be delighted if someone helped me out with this so I could see where I'm going wrong. I have made small attempt but the further I go to worst I get. I'd be happy if someone gave me some guidance please. Here is what the program should be like.

1. I have to enter integer numbers only if it's a floating number than it should display an error and that I need to try again. The minimum amount of numbers are 10.
2. Once all the numbers are entered it should display what the percentage of the numbers are even numbers.
3. At any time i can exit the program by typing "exit"

   ```
   int i;
   for(i=1; i<=10; ++i)

   printf("Enter 10 integers: ");  
   scanf("%d",&i);  
   printf("Enter the next integer or type exit to end the program: %d",i);

   system("PAUSE");    
   return (printf);
   ```

Comment: `1. Store numbers in array`...`2.use if-else statements`! Or if you don't want to use array,then,create a count variable for checking even numbers!

Comment: @shekharsuman 3. print answer

Comment: Are you familiar with `grep`? Can you imagine if `grep` behaved by first prompting "enter a regex", then prompting "enter a file to search"?  That would render it nearly useless.  Please consider changing your interface.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this program? Your are talking about floating numbers and using integer values.

Comment: Im trying to learn c.

Comment: You are using i variable in for statement and over on top of it trying to assign a value using scanf. Pls use different variables and there are many errors.

Comment: `return (printf);` :/

Answer (score 3):

Since you asked for guidance rather than a full working solution, here goes.

First you currently have

```
for(i=1; i<=10; ++i)

printf("Enter 10 integers: ");  
scanf("%d",&i);
```

The `for` will just loop around the next line, unless you use braces, i.e. it will print "Enter..." 10 times:

```
for(i=1; i<=10; ++i)
    printf("Enter 10 integers: ");  

scanf("%d",&i);
```

It may help to get used to putting everything you want to loop (even a one-liner) in braces:

```
for(i=1; i<=10; ++i)
{
    printf("Enter 10 integers: ");  
    scanf("%d",&i);  
    //...
}
```

Often people (with good reason) start at 0 in C:

```
for(i=0; i<10; ++i)
{
    printf("Enter 10 integers: ");  
    scanf("%d",&i);  
    //...
}
```

If you structure your code like that it may help to pull out a get_valid_input function

```
for(i=0; i<10; ++i)
{
    printf("Enter 10 integers: ");  
    get_valid_input(); //what do you intend to do with this?
    //...
}
```

with

```
int get_valid_input()
{
    int i;
    scanf("%d",&i);  //how do they type "exit"?
    //..
}
```

This needs thought though - should it return an `int`?
You could then store them somewhere.
But you could keep track of percentage of even numbers as you go.
Also, at any time you can press "exit" (type in the string or press a key?) so you need to be able to indicate that.

Don't forget to print the result, once you have worked it out. (Left as an exercise for the reader)

Answer (score 0):

```
int i, v, n=0, even;
int array[10] = {0};
char buff1[32], buff2[32];

printf("Enter 10 integers: \n");
for(i=1; i<=10; ++i){
    printf("Enter the next integer or type exit to end the program %d:\n", i);
    fgets(buff1, sizeof buff1, stdin);
    strcpy(buff2, strtok(buff1, " \t\n"));//trim
    if(strcmp(buff2, "exit")==0)
        break;
    if(1!=sscanf(buff2, "%d%s", &v, buff1)){
        printf("invalid input\n");
        --i;
        continue;
    }
    array[n++] = v;
}

for(even=i=0;i<n;++i){
    printf("%d ", array[i]);
    if((array[i] & 1) == 0)
        ++even;
}
printf("\n");
if(n)
    printf("Even proportions : %.1f%%\n", 100.0*even / n);
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
```